# How to make a serial pipeline for multiple targets a parallel pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

is it possible to do something like this in GitlabCI?

```
[prebuild] ----- [build A] --- [deploy A]
            \--- [build B] --- [deploy B]
             \-- [build C] --- [deploy C]
```

I've looked a lot into Gitlab documentation but could not find a way to achieve this. I basically don't want my deploy stage to wait for the build stage to be done, if a single build stage is done, its deploy stage related to that build should start.

A simple answer to that question could make this a single step, but I only want to deploy when tags are made. I really want a separate step, so this is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `needs` keyword. (Introduced in GitLab 12.2)
From Gitlab documentation:

> The `needs:` keyword enables executing jobs out-of-order, allowing you to implement a [directed acyclic graph](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/directed_acyclic_graph/index.html) in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`.
>   This lets you run some jobs without waiting for other ones, disregarding stage ordering so you can have multiple stages running concurrently.

Example and more details on some limitation are here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#needs